# Linux SUSE - How to install PHP 5.3.x on SUSE?

Tags: php, linux, php5, amazon-ec2, sles

I'm trying to install php 5.3.x on Suse/linux platform, but whenever I install and check it with phpinfo(); it shows php 5.2.

Any idea how to deal with it? please provide the detailed instructions. Thanks

BTW: I'm using Amazon EC2 with SUSE as its operating system image.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of SUSE should have PHP 5.3 by default, however maybe you're running an older version?

If so, you'd probably be best off compiling from source. Get the [download from here](http://www.php.net/downloads.php) and follow the instructions on how to compile and install.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that 5.2 was installed by default, and your 5.3 was installed to a different location. Check the install location of your 5.3 version, and make sure that's the default that Apache's using.

Answer (score 0):

See here for a complete upgrade path: http://gnuski.blogspot.fr/2012/05/suse-enterprise-111-installing-php-53.html

I just tested this on a SuSE 11 SP1 and it seems to work.